# 〜の：今日は、色々な日本一と世界一の話をしました

Tags: grammar, particle-の

How is の being used here?

> 今日は、色々な日本一と世界一の話をしました

Source: https://cijapanese.com/no-1-in-japan-vs-no-1-in-the-world/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This の marks the genitive case. You can read more [here](https://wildnihongo.com/grammar/no-genitive/).

Here, と is used to list nouns exhaustively. Nouns that are listed by this と create a noun phrase and can therefore occur in places where nouns can:

- 日本一と世界一 | Noun phrase

Note that 話をします is a verb phrase consisting of a noun, 話. This noun is modified by this other one 日本一と世界一 through の, meaning "a talk **about** Japan's best and the world's best."